# FLUTTER: Como mantener la pantalla encendida o activa

Tags: flutter, app, screen, android-settings, appsettings

tengo una aplicación de lectura y necesito agregar en configuraciones la opción para mantener la pantalla encendida, alguien sabe como hacerlo?

Esto es lo que dice la documentacion de android, pero nose en que lugar del codigo implementarlo para probar https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock?hl=es-419#screen

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
}
```

Comment: No deberías mirar la documentación de Android si estás trabajando con flutter. Son dos cosas diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [wakeloc](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock).

```
import 'package:wakelock/wakelock.dart';

// Para mantener la pantalla encendida:
Wakelock.enable();
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56918918/13419694